# In MS Access VBA Designer window all menus, ribbons and tootlbars are missing

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

The missing items make it impossible to use. Code can be written, but not executed and tested. I have tried many solutions, most of which are to restart the VBE, but that does not work. In fact, none have worked so far.  I have tried to grammatically get the part of the Windows back, but this has not worked, either.

I had been using the VBE to develop on this project for about a month.  During that time, all feature of the VBE were in place and seemed to be working correctly.  I had a problem with another Office module and had to run a complete repair on it.  When the re-installation came back, the VBE was without the normal parts ( menus, Toolbar, ribbon).  I found an article that had some code whose purpose was to customize the appearance and function of the VBE.  I ran this code, but it seemed to have no effect.

I also tried to construct the window using the right-click thing that are available, but it can't be done and when it is closed, it goes back to default configuration.

I am using Windows 10, Access 2016.

[image: 1 A graphic showing the issue with the Window]

Comment: A screenshot of what it looks like now might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is lacking details needed for anyone to be able to help you. That may explain the lack of comments or answers. Please add details about the "*tried many solutions*",  including what version of Access you are using. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Screenshot not uploaded properly.